# Trying to run Steiner algorithm in Networkx but the graph is in separate pieces

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graph-theory

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import geopandas as gpd
import momepy
import pcst_fast
from pyproj import CRS
import fiona

roads = gpd.read_file("ala3.gpkg")
roads['length'] = roads.geometry.length
lens = list(roads.length.copy())
roads.crs = "EPSG:4326"
roads = roads.to_crs(crs='EPSG:4326')

pts = gpd.read_file("alapts.gpkg")

F = momepy.gdf_to_nx(roads, approach="primal", length="length")

gdf_F = momepy.nx_to_gdf(F)[1]


coords = {}
for i, j, in enumerate(list(G.nodes)):
    coords[i] = j


lengths = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "length")
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, values=lengths, name="weight")

G = nx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G, label_attribute='old_label')

# define parameters for input, choose num of random nodes

num_steiners = 200
edge_list = [[int(u), int(v)] for u, v in G.edges()]
node_id = [i for i in range(len(G.nodes))]
prizes = [0]*len(G.nodes)

selection = random.sample(list(range(len(prizes))), num_steiners)

for s in selection:
    prizes[s] = 9999 # some high value to catch no matter what

costs = np.array(list(nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "length").values()))
root = -1
num_clusters = 1

vertices, eg = pcst_fast.pcst_fast(edge_list, prizes, costs, root, num_clusters, "gw", 1)


print("Are all steiner nodes a subset of the outputed vertices?")
print(set(selection).issubset(set(node_list)))
```

I'm trying to run the vertices, edges = pcst_fast(edges, prizes, costs, root, num_clusters, pruning, verbosity_level) function from https://github.com/fraenkel-lab/pcst_fast to calculate a steiner path. It only generates a piece of the path connecting the nodes because the graph is fractured into separate components. How do I connect them all into one graph?

[image: incomplete steiner path]

Comment: Is your question how you can combine all points, so you can use the algorithm on that? Or do you want to combine the different paths?

Comment: I want to combine all disconnected components, which should make it work

Answer (score 0):

To combine the components in your graph:

```
WHILE not all nodes have been moved to a component
   CONSTRUCT empty component
   MOVE random node not in any component to component
       LOOP M over nodes not moved to a component
           LOOP C over nodes in component
               IF M & C are connected
                     Move M to component
                     BREAK from LOOP C
SELECT largest component
    LOOP over other components
         SELECT A node in largest component
         SELECT B node in other component
         ADD link between A and B
```

The selection of A and B in last loop can be at random.  However if you have more information, such as the distance between nodes, then you can improve this be selecting the two nodes that are closest.